# Can I view previous versions of publication metadata values?

Tags: 2009, metadata

Is there a way to view previous publication metadata values using the content management explorer (CME) in Tridion 2009 SP1?  I'd also like to view things such as who made the last change and when it was made.

If it is not available through the CME, can this information be retrieved via one of the database tables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get version history on the following items:

- Component
- Component Template
- Template Building Block
- Page Template
- Page
- Schema

Organizational items don't have a versioned history. To keep a history on this type of information, consider placing it in a "configuration" component or using the Event System to record the details in Application Data or a non-Tridion database.

**Edit**: added TBB to the list of versioned items.

Comment: `Template Building Block` is also versioned. `Publication` is not versioned.